# Is there any orthogonal basis set that satisfies an integral equation appearing in physics?

Tags: linear-algebra, integral-kernel

I am considering the following integral equation
$$
f(x) = \int_{-W}^W \frac{\exp(-x  y)}{\cosh(y)} g(y) dy,
$$
where $-1 \le x \le 1$, $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ are real functions.
This integral equation appears in many fields of physics.
$W~(>0)$ is a given real number, acting as a cutoff energy in physics.
A common practice in our field is mapping this to a singular value problem by using uniform or non-uniform meshes for $x$ and $y$ to obtain the numerical solutions of $f(x)$, $g(y)$.

There are several known facts from numerical results for $W\ll 1$.
First, the $l$-th singular value $\lambda_l$ decays exponentially (or faster) with respect to $l$. It seems that the $l$-th solutions of $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ converge to the $l$-th Legendre polynomial as $W\rightarrow 0$ (after $y$ is rescaled from $[-W,W]$ to $[-1,1]$).

Is there any orthogonal basis set that satisfies this equation for $W>0$?
Is it possible to solve the equation and obtain the explicit form of the orthogonal basis?
Our guess was that some polynomials satisfy the equation. But, we did not make it.

Comment: Since the kernel function is square integrable, general theory says that there exists such an basis. That a consequence of the fact that the singular value decomposition also exists for compact operators between Hilbert spaces. Calculating this basis is another thing...

Comment: Thank you for the comment. We're wondering if it is possible to calculate the explicit form of the basis. Our naive guess was some hypergeometric functions may be the solution because the solution converges to Legendre polynomials as W->0.

Comment: The latest edition of Mathematica (v11) can solve some integral equations -- does it give anything useful?  https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/symbolic-and-numeric-calculus/solve-a-fredholm-integral-equation.html?product=mathematica

Comment: Thank you. In our integral equation, we need to determine f(x) and g(y) simultanouesly. But, the equation is reduced to a Fredholm Integral equation of the second kind for g(y) once we integrate out f(x). Its kernel is given by \int_x^{-1}^1 K(x,y) K(x, y^\prime), where K
 is the kernel of our original integral equation. I do not have a license of the Mathematica. But, I could ask my college to give it a try.

Comment: I reformulated our integral equation as a homogeneous fredholm integral equation of the second kind for g(y). But, Mathematica (v11) did not give any useful results.